# Is there any way to simulate Generic Associated Types / Associated Type Constructors in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, associated-types

I'm making a graph processing module in Rust. The core of the module models the idea of having multiple containers which hold the data in the graph. For example, I may have a graph whose inner structure is an `HashMap` or maybe `AdjacencyMatrix` etc.

These containers must implement a trait:

```
trait GraphData<V> {
    fn has_edge(&self, v: &V, u: &V) -> bool;
    fn nodes(&self) -> Iterator<V>; // Here's the problem...
}
```

I can't just return a trait in my trait definition. I know I must use trait object, but I don't want to `Box` it. I would like to make the container provide its own `NodeIter` struct. However, I would be stuck with the same problem explained in [Associated type constructors, part 1: basic concepts and introduction](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/11/02/associated-type-constructors-part-1-basic-concepts-and-introduction/). The post explains about associated type constructors (ATC) which do not exist in Rust now.  My `GraphData` resembles the generic `Collection` described.

Is there any workaround I could use to "simulate" ATC or any pattern specific to Rust I could use for this situation?

I don't want to depend on dynamic dispatch and resort to using `Box` or the `dyn` keyword.

I thought to define a struct `NodeIter` for each type of graph container
I created in my module and add "nodes" inside the implementation of the container itself. However, I find this to be poor code reuse.

Comment: For the record, the name currently used for associated type constructors in Rust is generic associated types (GATs). Tracking issue [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265).

Comment: Did you mean to have `self` parameters on those methods?

Comment: I think that [petgraph](https://crates.io/crates/petgraph) already does what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes I did see it, however, petgraph is not as generic as I want, moreover what I'm trying to do is a proof of concept for a school project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the answer by Anders Kaseorg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165795/2408867) already explains: you might not need GATs here, if you can live with cloning your `Vec` containing the vertices. However, that's probably not what you want. Instead, you usually want to have an iterator that references the original data.

To achieve that, you in fact ideally want to use GATs. But since they are not part of the language yet, let's tackle your main question: **Is there any way to simulate Generic Associated Types?** I actually wrote a very extensive blog post about this topic: [**“Solving the Generalized Streaming Iterator Problem without GATs”**](http://lukaskalbertodt.github.io/2018/08/03/solving-the-generalized-streaming-iterator-problem-without-gats.html).

Summarizing the article:

- The easiest way for you is to box the iterator and return it as trait object:

  ```
  fn nodes(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<&'_ V> + '_>
  ```

  As you said, you don't want that, so that's out.
- You can add a lifetime parameter to your trait and use that lifetime in your associated type and the `&self` receiver:

  ```
  trait GraphData<'s, V: 's> {
      type NodesIter: Iterator<Item = &'s V>;
      fn nodes(&'s self) -> Self::NodesIter;
  }

  struct MyGraph<V> {
      nodes: Vec<V>,
  }

  impl<'s, V: 's> GraphData<'s, V> for MyGraph<V> {
      type NodesIter = std::slice::Iter<'s, V>;
      fn nodes(&'s self) -> Self::NodesIter {
          self.nodes.iter()
      }
  }
  ```

  This works! However, now you have an annoying lifetime parameter in your trait. That might be fine (apart from annoyance) in your case, but it can actually be a critical problem in some situations, so this might or might not work for you.
- You can push the lifetime parameter a level deeper by having a helper trait which works as type level function from lifetime to type. This makes the situation a little less annoying, because the lifetime parameter is not in your main trait anymore, but it suffers from the same limitation as the prior workaround.
- You can also go a completely different path and write an iterator wrapper that contains a reference to your graph.

  This is just a rough sketch, but the basic idea works: your actual inner iterator doesn't contain any reference to the graph (so its type does not need the `self` lifetime). The graph reference is instead stored in a specific type `Wrap` and passed to the inner iterator for each `next` call.

  Like this:

  ```
  trait InnerNodesIter { /* ... */ }

  struct Wrap<'graph, G: GraphData, I: InnerNodesIter> {
      graph: &'graph G,
      iter: I,
  }

  type NodesIterInner: InnerNodesIter;
  fn nodes(&self) -> Wrap<'_, Self, Self::NodesIterInner>;
  ```

  Then you can implement `Iterator` for `Wrap`. You just need some interface to the inner iterator, which you can pass the reference to the graph. Something like `fn next(&mut self, graph: &Graph) -> Option<...>`. You need to define the interface in `InnerNodesIter`.

  This of course suffers from being very verbose. And it also might be a bit slower, depending on how your iterator works.

The short and sad summary is: **there is no satisfying workaround that works in every situation.**

---

My opinion in this case: I work on a project where this exact situation occurred multiple times. In my case, I just used the `Box` solution as it's very easy and works fine. The only downside is speed (allocation and dynamic dispatch), but the allocation doesn't happen in a tight loop (except if you have a large number of graphs, each with only very few nodes -- unlikely) and the optimizer is probably capable of devirtualizing the dynamic calls in most cases (after all, the real type information is only one function boundary away).

Answer (score 6):

The problem you’ve described is solved with plain [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types).  It does not require [generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265), a.k.a. associated type constructors.  This already works in stable Rust.

```rs
trait GraphData<V> {
    type Nodes: Iterator<Item = V>;
    fn has_edge(&self, v: &V, u: &V) -> bool;
    fn nodes(&self) -> Self::Nodes;
}

struct Graph<V> {
    nodes: Vec<V>,
    edges: Vec<(V, V)>,
}

impl<V: Clone + Eq> GraphData<V> for Graph<V> {
    type Nodes = vec::IntoIter<V>;
    fn has_edge(&self, u: &V, v: &V) -> bool {
        self.edges.iter().any(|(u1, v1)| u == u1 && v == v1)
    }
    fn nodes(&self) -> Self::Nodes {
        self.nodes.clone().into_iter()
    }
}
```

`Nodes` has no type or lifetime parameters (it’s not `Nodes<T>` or `Nodes<'a>`), so it’s not generic.

If you wanted the `Nodes` type to be able hold a reference to `Self` (to avoid the `clone()`), *then* `Nodes` would need to be generic with a lifetime parameter.  That’s not the only way to avoid the `clone()`, though: you could use `Rc`.

Comment: Another way to iterate over references with different iterator types without GATs is to box it up and use dynamic dispatch: `-> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'_ V> + '_>`

Comment: @Anders Kaseorg That's the point I'm getting at, if I don't want any clone in my code, I would need to declare a lifetime parameter to Nodes, however, the compiler will complain about a lifetime not in scope as described in the blogpost I linked in my premise.