# Is it possible to emulate `impl Trait` in return position in trait methods without using trait objects?

Tags: rust, traits

I have somewhat followed the progress on the existential types and GAT proposals (though I'm not entirely sure which one is most applicable for my problem), but those are not available yet.

Here is roughly what I'd like to do:

```
trait Trait: Sized {
    fn generic_associated<T>() -> impl Assoc<Item = T, Trait = Self>;
}

trait Assoc: Sized {
    type Item;
    type Trait: Trait;
}
```

This doesn't compile because you can't have `impl Trait` in return position in trait methods. Is there some way to emulate something like that? I know I could return `Box<dyn Assoc<Item = T, Trait = Self>>`, but that is not an option for my specific case.

I've read [this](https://vorner.github.io/2019/02/03/hacks.html) blog post (the section called 'Anonymous Associated Types'), which claims something along those lines could be emulated using `Fn` traits and blanket implementations, but I fail to how to apply the given example to my problem, since that example uses a freestanding function in the end to avoid having to name the concrete type.

**edit**

While the post does not explicitly claim to emulate existential types or generic associated types, it does demonstrate a technique using `Fn` traits to use an anonymous associated type. Is this something that could potentially be used for emulating existential types?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Using impl Trait in Trait definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39482131/155423). If there **were** any workarounds, that's where they would live. If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Is there any way to simulate Associated Type Constructors in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54161441/155423).

Comment: Thanks for the links, I had already read the first one before posting. I suppose my question is more closely linked to the blogpost I linked (which is only a few days old). I take it the claim made in there w.r.t anonymous associated types is somewhat misleading then?

Comment: *my question is more closely linked to the blogpost I linked* — if that's the case, then you need to include the pertinent contents / concepts of the blog post *in the question* and ask a specific question about it (e.g. "how do I use the technique..." or "is the technique ... a lie").

Comment: I think for the trick you mentioned, you would to have to add `type Assoc` to `Trait`, and possibly even adjust a bit more.